# Need help finding a linear sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given a machine that can compute the kth smallest item of an Array A in (√) time. Find a recursive function that can sort A in linear time corresponding to n which is the length of A.

First I tried to optimize some of the sorting algorithms I knew using this new property but the best I could do was O(n^3/2) and currently I'm wondering whether if it is possible or not.

Comment: Using this machine, you can easily turn quicksort into a true O(n log(n)) algorithm (without the machine, quicksort is O(n log(n)) in expectation on a randomly shuffled list, but worst-case Θ(n^2) on an adversarial list). But writing an O(n) sorting algorithm still sounds hard.

Comment: You might get better answers on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: Same question (with no response yet) is here [cs.stackexchange linear sort method in special machine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131623/using-a-special-given-machine-find-a-recursive-function-that-can-sort-a-in-linea)

Comment: If you keep finding the smallest item you can do it in O(*√), which is what you also wrote in your post I can't see that you can do it without going through all the items though.